# How to compile GNU C Library (glibc) with llvm?

Tags: llvm

I wanna know how to compile the GNU C Library not with gcc, but with llvm. I can't find any solution in internet. ask for help

when I use command `../glibc-2.23/configure --disable-sanity-checks CC="clang"` to build glibc. it reports error

`checking version of gawk... 4.1.3, ok
checking if clang is sufficient to build libc... no
checking for nm... nm
configure: error: 
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: compiler
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.`

I don't know how to do. my llvm version is the newest version.

Comment: you can look into clang (https://clang.llvm.org/) to start-with.

Comment: Does setting CC=clang not work?

Comment: it doesn't work，I`ve tried

Comment: @Abhinav Upadhyay

Comment: The configure message clearly says that clang is not sufficient to build glibc. On looking around found an old thread on LLVM mailing list which says clang can't yet build glibc (http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2014-September/077263.html). Nothing more recent comes up on search but my guess is that glibc might be using some GCC specific extensions which are not present in clang.

Comment: Currently glibc can't be built with Clang/LLVM, but both clang and glibc people are working towards it, see [the blog](https://maskray.me/blog/2021-10-10-when-can-glibc-be-built-with-clang).